# Reasons Why Custom Validator May Not Be Showing Error Msg?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, validation

Unfortunately I can't show you the code so I am just going to have to explain the problem.

I have a detail view that is in a update panel. I added a custom validator that should appear open the condition if Radio Button A is selected TextBox A must have a value in it.

I setup an OnServerValidate method that checked for this and if it fails then I set args.Valid to false.

However my error message never appears. If I look through IE Developer Tool I see my customer validator with the hard coded message but it is hidden(visibility: hidden).

I tried to find the customvalidator and force visibility to show and even went as far to try to remove it through customValidator.Style.Remove("visibility") yet nothing works. The message is always hidden.

The page does fail validation as if that condition is met my page won't save. It just won't show my message that I set in custom validator.

**Edit**

I also tried doing `Visible="true"` in the aspx code of the custom validator and it stil will not show the error msg and in developer toolkit shows it as hidden.

Comment: "Unfortunately I can't show you the code so I am just going to have to explain the problem." Could you make a simplfied example that you *can* show?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and set a breakpoint to step into the validation routine? I'd also verify the page is flagged as invalid during the page_load event.

Comment: @Tim - Yes I stepped through the debugger and saw it goes through the onValidationServer method and gets set to false. In the btn submit event there is Page.IsValid that checks o see if the page is valid. It does not get past this point as the page is not valid. I can put a Page.IsValid and see what is says in page_load

Comment: @MarkByers - I thought of that but not sure if I can recreate it as there is so much going on in the page where the custom validator is and on top of it I did not write this code so not sure if I will be able to recreate the scenario.

Comment: Just for yuks - maybe explicitly set your foreground and background colors on the validator?

Comment: Nope, I set error msg, backcolor,forecolor,visablity,enabled and nothing will make it show.

Comment: Does it change anything when you set `Display` to `Static` or `Dynamic` on the `Validator` control? I remember having had problems with validation messages not showing up as expected.

Comment: Ya I tried Static and Dynamic. Does not change anything. As I said I can see the control and I can remove the hidden visibility with IE developer toolbar and it will show up then. So it is there but just not unhiding itself when it should. What I find is so weird I set the default control to be visible. I would think it would show then.

Comment: I've got the same problem.  The customvalidator I'm using I set isvalid on server side for the control based on my own logic... I can see that the validator is rendered out where I added it but it's style attribute is set to display:none (I use dynamic).  I have set controltovalidate and all my other validators work just fine.... just this one customvalidator that's being a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I tried everything, changing the style attribute on the validator, using Javascript to change the style, Jquery, etc. Nothing would work, its style was always "visibility:hidden".

Eventually I ended up doing the most ridiculous workaround by just adding a label with my error message:

```
<asp:Label ID="ErrorLabel" runat="server" Visible="False" CssClass="validator-red">
    Error message here
</asp:Label>
```

and manually displaying it in the validation event handler:

```
protected void Validator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args) {
    // Validation code, set args.IsValid here.

    ErrorLabel.Visible = !args.IsValid;
}
```

That's functionality that's meant to be included with all validators, but it looks like MS stuffed it up on this one. At least this works reliably. Also don't forget to set `Display="None"` on the validator as you won't be needing that.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar problem myself and found this thread, just before I found an answer...not sure if it's still worthwhile, but here's what I did.

1)  I added the following (VB.net code, but you should be able to port it to C#):

```
My_Custom_Validator.Attributes.Add("class", "invalid")
```

2)  I created a CSS invalid class rule:

```
.invalid {display:  block !important;  visibility:  visible !important;}
```

The !important will override the inline CSS created by the .NET code.  Setting it on display:  block; isn't necessary, but I put it just in case.

This doesn't answer your question as to why the visibility:  hidden; inline CSS appears...it's just a workaround.

Comment: `!important` in a `<style>` or `<link>`'d CSS file will not override in-line style attributes